# Format MySQL Script In Terminal Through AppleScript - Quote Escaping Problems

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, escaping, applescript

I'm currently writing an AppleScript to trigger a MySQL script to run in order to send a csv every day at a certain time using a calendar event.

I believe I have the general idea on both parts correct. This is a version of the MySQL script (which works when run directly in MySQL):

```
SET @sql_text := CONCAT('SELECT "ID", "FirstName", "LastName", "Employer", "Activist/Lead"
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT e.id, m.firstname, m.lastname, e.employer, (CASE WHEN m.Lead="X" THEN "Lead" ELSE "Activist" END) AS "Activist/Lead"
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN people m ON e.id = m.id
WHERE ((STR_TO_DATE(e.startdate,"%m/%d/%Y") >= SUBDATE(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AND (e.eventtype IN("House Party","Blitz","Politics"))
GROUP BY e.id
HAVING count(e.id)>=1) t
   INTO OUTFILE \'/Users/Ryan/Activists_', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d'), '.csv\'
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
   LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\'
');

PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE s1;
DROP PREPARE s1;
```

That MySQL script alone does a good job at creating a .csv with my naming convention into the folder of my choosing. But as you can see there are lots of single and double quotes (some with escapes already) that I need in there to make the MySQL script work.

Though when I put it into AppleScript to run through Terminal, I get all sorts of errors due to the quotes:

[image: AppleScript Error]

As you can see, it's highlighting "ID" because it's the first appearance of double quotes in the MySQL script. I've tried changing all the double quotes to `\"` but it seems to just get more confusing -- particularly at the `INTO OUTFILE` section because that's also when the single quotes start showing up. (And at that point [single quotes towards the end] it starts giving the error `Expected “"” but found unknown token.`)

Does anyone know a way I can restructure the escape quotes to make AppleScript not give me errors, even though I need the quotes to look the way they do in order for the MySQL script to run properly? Feels like they're fighting against each other.

Comment: You should be able to get the double quotes to pass just using a single backslash: \"

Comment: @CraigSmith    When I do that, it doesn't give me an error until I get to the single quotes down at the `INTO OUTFILE` section where I'm already using escapes -- and, at least at my skill level, gets real confusing.

Comment: @CraigSmith    Also the syntax error when it hits the single quotes towards the end changes from the screenshot above to `Expected “"” but found unknown token.`

Comment: That usually means that you are missing a character somewhere.  When I do this stuff, I write it out in TextMate first (to help keep the quotes and escapes straight), then copy it over to AppleScript.

Comment: @CraigSmith    Thanks. But doesn't it make sense though? The first single quote is right before my first `SELECT` statement and the error hits on the second single quote which is right after `INTO OUTFILE` -- so it makes sense to me as to why it'd think the script is over and doesn't know what to do. That, and I'm already using an escape for MySQL purposes there: `INTO OUTFILE \'/Users/Ryan/Activists_', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d'), '.csv\'`

Comment: Sense or no, if the AppleScript does not compile, something is wrong, and in these situations, it is nearly always a quote or an escape.  Have you considered converting to SQLite?  It is built into OS X, and much easier to deal with under these circumstances.  Another trick is to assemble your SELECT statement one object at a time, compile it, and then add other objects and commands.  Takes longer, but fewer syntax errors.

Comment: @CraigSmith    Thanks again for the advice! Do you by chance have an answer that would work you could submit? I'd be open to whatever -- I just use MySQL/AppleSciprts/Terminal because those are the things I know fairly well, would be open to more things. All I know is when I add the `\"` to the double quotes it works but then it breaks on the single quotes even there there's no obvious fix (like missing a closing single quote, or anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just stopped trying to post the script directly into AppleScript and used Terminal to grab my script `activists.sql` directly from its text file by using this: `do script with command "mysql 'database' < activist.sql"` within AppleScript after telling it to open Terminal.